# how to append data in Shared Preference in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I tried to append the data in shared preference file by using

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myData", MODE_APPEND);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("name", userName.getText().toString());
editor.putString("password", password.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

But I found that new value overwrites the old value. Will you help me to fix this issue?

Comment: What do you mean overwrites the old values ? You mean values other than `name` and `password` as gone ?

Comment: Data in `SharedPreferences` is stored and retreived in the form of key-value pair. And hence when you `putString` to key 'name' or 'password', you override the previously saved value. You can read about it here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: the values name and password are overwritten by new values when i tried to append into the existing shared preference xml file.

Comment: So you want a list of name-password pairs ?

Comment: K Jayesh. I ll try it and update you. thank you.

Comment: Yes, i want to create a list of username and password

Comment: If you want to save list of usernames and passwords then better to go with sqlite(Database)

Comment: can u pls suggest, is tr any solution MODE_APPEND itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MODE_APPEND` doesn't mean that you add multiple values for each key. It means that if the file already exists it is appended to and not erased . We usually used `MODE_PRIVATE`.

As for saving multiple names and passwords, you can take a look at `putStringSet(string key Set<String> values` Method.

You can save the for each key a set of string values. You can separate the username and password by some special character or string. You may even serialize an object to json.

So basically what you need to do is:

1. Get the list of values from Shared Preferences
2. Append the current value to the list.
3. Save the List back to Shared Preferences.

Comment: If its MODE_PRIVATE, the old data which belong to all keys in the preference file will be deleted?

Comment: @BrightVarghese No. Unless you overwrite the same key. You need to retreive the list from the sharedPreferences, add a values to it. And then save it back.